# How to get the original name of embedded File from package word with c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a problem with openxml in c#. Im able to get embedded file from openxml package (office word) but with an other name like worksheet1.xml stocked in /word/embedding....

I would like to get the original name of this attached file.
How can i do that ?

Im using this code from msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSOfficeDocumentFileExtract-e5afce86

Comment: You can't. Unless Word happened to save that information as part of the information associated with the reference to the embedded file in document.xml, which sometimes happens. But I don't think it's something you can count on.

Comment: I can get the emf file from document.xml which is associated with the embedded file it contain the name of the file /media/image1.emf but i can't get this text from the emf image.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be in the image. If it were anywhere, then it would be saved as an element or attribute in the xml. But even if it were, it's not something that you could rely on, so really, unless you program an interface for the user to embed these objects and make saving the file information part of that tool, there is no way to know from what file the embedded object was created.